# Is google invisible-recaptcha any less secure compared to recaptcha-v2 checkbox?

Tags: recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

My company is considering moving from **recaptcha-v2 checkbox** to **invisible recaptcha**.

Are there any pros/cons to this in terms of security and cross browser compatibility?

Thank you.

Comment: In my experience, the invisible captcha works best over the checkbox. Noticed less spam.